# How to validate in dynamic forms in angular?

Tags: angular

In short ,below code is my form code(pleaase ignore Chinese,that's not important)

```
 getQuestions() {
    const questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [
        new DropdownQuestion({
            key: 'homePlace',
            label: '籍贯',
            options: [
                { key: '杭州', value: '杭州' },
                { key: '温州', value: '温州' },
                { key: '上虞', value: '上虞' },
                { key: '诸暨', value: '诸暨' },
            ],
            order: 3
        }),
        new TextboxQuestion({
            key: 'userName',
            label: '用户名',
            value: '茶荼先生',
            order: 1,
            rule: [
                Validators.required
            ]
        }),
        new TextboxQuestion({
            key: 'password',
            label: '密码',
            order: 2,
            rule: [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(6),
                Validators.maxLength(10),
            ]
        })
    ];
    return questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);//排序
}
```

And below code is my html.

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
<label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

<div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

    <input nz-input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key" [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">

    <nz-select style="width: 120px;" nzAllowClear [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key">
        <nz-option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [nzValue]="opt.key" [nzLabel]="opt.value"></nz-option>
    </nz-select>

</div>
<div style="color:red;" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} can't be empty</div>
<div style="color:red;" *ngIf="!minlength">can not less than 6</div>
```

here is the question.How to validate single validation rule?Such as minlength.
I try to validate it like this

```
get isValid() { return this.form.controls[this.question.key].valid; }
get minlength() { return this.form.controls[this.question.key].errors.minlength; }
```

The function `isValid` works.However,the system alert me that `ERROR TypeError: "this.form.controls[this.question.key].errors is null"`.Why?
What should I do if i want to validate minlength?

Comment: `this.question.key`  what does this piece of code return ?

Comment: Try adding like `minlength=100` in your input field also.

Comment: check if form exist before using ternary operator:, e.g get minlenght(){return this.form?this.form.controls[this.question.key]?this.form.controls[this.question.key].errors.minlength:null:null:null}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to make sure that errors object has been filled:

```
hasError(kind: string) {
  return this.form.controls[this.question.key].errors &&
         this.form.controls[this.question.key].errors[kind];
}

get minlength() { return this.hasError('minlength'); }

get required() { return this.hasError('required'); }
```

Also your controls should be instantiated accordingly in

```
toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[]) {
  let group: any = {};

  questions.forEach(question => {
    group[question.key] = new FormControl(question.value || '', question.rule);
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                               sync validators

  });
  return new FormGroup(group);
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/K3UqbKtmNDvSAveDAkQe?open=app%2Fquestion-control.service.ts)**